# How do you add items to a listbox on a second form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

Working on a project for school that has 2 forms.  I want to add items to the listbox in the Display form when I click the show data button.  It's showing the form but the form is blank.  I think this is because the form object is being created 2x once when I click the add button and another when I click the show data button.  How can I create a new object of the display form that can be used in any method in my main form?

Sorry there is a few things in here that I am still working on that were just ideas.  I am a beginner so please keep the help in simple terms if at all possible.  Thanks :)

```
    private void addEmployee(Employee newEmployee)
    {
        //Get data from textboxes and use set methods in employee class
        newEmployee.Name = EmployeeNameTextBox.Text;
        newEmployee.BirthDate = EmployeeBirthDateTextBox.Text;
        newEmployee.Dept = EmployeeDeptTextBox.Text;
        newEmployee.HireDate = EmployeeHireDateTextBox.Text;
        newEmployee.Salary = EmployeeSalaryTextBox.Text;

    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //New list for employee class objects - employeelist
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();

        //Create new instance of Employee class - newEmployee
        Employee newEmployee = new Employee();

        bool errorCheck = false;
        CheckForms(ref errorCheck);

        if (!errorCheck)
        {
            //Gather input from text boxes and pass newEmployee object
            addEmployee(newEmployee);

            //Add object to employeeList
            employeeList.Add(newEmployee);


            Display myDisplay = new Display();
            myDisplay.OutputListBox.Items.Add(" Bob");

                //" " + newEmployee.BirthDate + " " + 
                //newEmployee.Dept + " " + newEmployee.HireDate + " " + newEmployee.Salary);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two separate instances of `mydisplay`.Create a single instance when the Form Loads and refer to that when you call `ShowDataButton_Click`

```
  namespace WK4
    {
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
Display myDisplay;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //Method to clear form input boxes
        private void ClearForm()
        {
            EmployeeNameTextBox.Text = "";
            EmployeeBirthDateTextBox.Text = "";
            EmployeeDeptTextBox.Text = "";
            EmployeeHireDateTextBox.Text = "";
            EmployeeSalaryTextBox.Text = "";
            FooterLabel.Text = "";
        }

        //Method to check for blank input on textboxes
        private void CheckForms(ref bool error)            
        {

            if (EmployeeNameTextBox.Text == "" || EmployeeBirthDateTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave any fields blank");
                error = true;
            }

            else if (EmployeeDeptTextBox.Text == "" || EmployeeHireDateTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave any fields blank");
                error = true;
            }

            else if (EmployeeSalaryTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave any fields blank");
                error = true;
            }
            else
                error = false;
        } 

        private void addEmployee(Employee newEmployee)
        {
            //Get data from textboxes and use set methods in employee class
            newEmployee.Name = EmployeeNameTextBox.Text;
            newEmployee.BirthDate = EmployeeBirthDateTextBox.Text;
            newEmployee.Dept = EmployeeDeptTextBox.Text;
            newEmployee.HireDate = EmployeeHireDateTextBox.Text;
            newEmployee.Salary = EmployeeSalaryTextBox.Text;

        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //New list for employee class objects - employeelist
            List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();

            //Create new instance of Employee class - newEmployee
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee();

            bool errorCheck = false;
            CheckForms(ref errorCheck);

            if (!errorCheck)
            {
                //Gather input from text boxes and pass newEmployee object
                addEmployee(newEmployee);

                //Add object to employeeList
                employeeList.Add(newEmployee);


                Display myDisplay = new Display();
                myDisplay.OutputListBox.Items.Add(" Bob");

                    //" " + newEmployee.BirthDate + " " + 
                    //newEmployee.Dept + " " + newEmployee.HireDate + " " + newEmployee.Salary);

                //Clear Form after adding data
                ClearForm();

                //Print footer employee saved info
                FooterLabel.Text = ("Employee " + newEmployee.Name + " saved.");
            }  
        }

        //Exit the form/program
        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //Method to clear the form and reset focus
        private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearForm();
            EmployeeNameTextBox.Focus();
        }

        private void ShowDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            myDisplay.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     myDisplay = new Display();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Solved - Thanks.. So just for my own information adding a line like this before the form code creates a new object of Display type referenced with myDisplay variable and lets me use it throughout the entire main form without creating a new object each time? Display myDisplay = new Display();

Answer (score 0):

You are making 2 different instances of display class, in first instance you are adding data and you are displaying it using the second instance thats why you are getting a blank form
create a display class object on your MainForm_Load

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Display myDisplay = new Display();
    }
```

and the use this object (myDisplay) to add and display data in your AddButton_Click and ShowDataButton_Click methods respectively.

Comment: Hey I can't get it to work when I create the object in form_load event handler.  It only works when I put the create statement above the main form like the above post said to do. Why is this?  Wouldn't form_load do the same thing?

Comment: sry my mistake, you will declare the Display class object in main class and then initialize it on form load so that you can access it from everywhere in your code.